# Установка Git в Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, git

При попытке установки git в ubuntu 16.04 появляется вот такое сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Команды:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

В [Инструкции](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git) прочитал:

> Для установки Git'а вам понадобятся библиотеки, от которых он зависит:
>   curl, zlib, openssl, expat и libiconv. Например, если в вашей системе
>   менеджер пакетов — yum (Fedora), или apt-get (Debian, Ubuntu), можно
>   воспользоваться следующими командами, чтобы разрешить все зависимости:

Команда:

```
apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext \
  libz-dev libssl-dev
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне установить git? Спасибо.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очистил `sources.list` от всякого барахла.
Установил галочки в пунктах ниже и повторил попытку установки. Получилось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем спасибо.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa - последняя стабильная версия гита.

Comment: мне автоматом 2.7.4 установило. спасибо

Comment: Ну, текущая стабильная - `2.13.2`.

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что в вашем sources.list нет репозиториев с нужным пакетом. Судя по выводу команды apt-get update, у вас там что-то забыли репозитории от Хрома, а системные куда-то пропали. Исправте эту проблему и счастье вернется к вам.

Comment: как мне это исправить может знаете? или может лучше его удалить и создать новый?

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/